# Best Place to Put a Comparator

Tags: java, comparator

I am sorry if I am asking something that has been answered already but I could not find a reference. My question is where is the best place to put a comparator which layer does it belong to.For example I need a list of User Objects sorted by users date of birth then surname and then first name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case if would put it on the domain class and sort it in the dao during fetch meaning have two methods(or more based on Comaprision types) on dao one to just get a list of unsorted object e.g. getUsers() and one method for sorted list e.g getSortedUers(); ofcourse you can only have a sorted method but always calling a sort is an over head if no sort is required.

Answer (score 4):

If the comparator is intrinsic to the object (e.g. it's the only way of ordering it that makes sense), then I would just implement `Comparable` on the object.

If the comparator is one of many (e.g. a `Comparator` instance), and only makes sense in a particular context, then I'd place the comparator class in that layer.

Comment: If an object can be compared in many ways, maybe it's not the best idea to just implement the Comparable interface. By doing so you limit the ways of comparing the objects to 1. Take a Person class. You might want to sort Person objects by birth date or by height, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using database, then best way is to sort it in query itself, using `order by`

Comment: The question is tagged `java` and not `database`.

Answer (score 0):

The general answer would be: put it where it is most required :-)

This depends a lot on your actual design and architecture. In general, either you can put it next to your user object, or into the layer which uses it most (or exclusively).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, if you use database or some external service and it's possible to sort there it's best way. But if you need to sort objects in your application it depends on your architecture. There are 2 variants. If you need sort only once - create anonymous class then you won't store reference on this object. If you need to make sort several times you can store it as static field of class or a non-static field.

Comment: Thanks but thats not what I a asking sorry.